# django multiple image uploading store uploaded image in a list

Tags: python, django, forms

My form

```
<form method="get" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

<input type="file" name="image" multiple />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

and here user can select and post multiple images.

When user posts multiple images at once I want to save them in a list so that I can iterate over them.

My view:

```
def MediaAddView(request):
# Here I want the list of all uploaded images
images = request.GET.get('image',None)
print images
if request.method == "POST":
    mod = Model()
    mod.thumb = one image from the list of image by iterating.
    mod.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("myUrl")
else:
    return render_to_response("anything.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What I want is when user upload multiple image, all the images should be in a list.

Like so that I can iterate `for image in images`

Here when I did `print images` it prints only last image of the uploaded images. How can I store all the images into list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload files with a GET request, only with a POST. And the files will then be found in `request.FILES`, so you can iterate over `request.FILES.getlist('image')` directly.

Comment: thank you... I made my form a post. and did images = request.FILES.getlist('image').. Its giving me what I wanted... but the problem is when I refresh the page an emptly list is already there why ?